# Is there an easy way to force VB.net to update the UI?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have been having a really difficult time with this, and it's almost unbelievable there is no way to force the UI to update. All I want is for the computer to actually show the LoadingImg before moving on the the next calls. I've tried so many different things from threads,tasks,OnClientClick, Asyn/Await etc. Most of the obvious methods like Refresh & Invoke are not methods for aspx.net. Is there no easy way to call on the UI to update itself? What exactly should I be doing?

```
Protected Async Sub BtnModSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    LoadingImg.Visible = True
    BtnDelete_Click()
    BtnSaveSchedule_Click(sender, e, 1)
    Call Response.Redirect("~/Schedule.aspx")
End Sub
```

I have also tried using Client Side with the code

```
            <asp:Image runat="server" ID="LoadingImg" src="../Content/Images/wait2.gif" style="height: 75%; width: 75%" visible="false"/>
            <script type="text/javascript">

                function validate() {
                    document.getElementById('LoadingImg').style.visibility = 'true';
                }
            </script>
<asp:Button ID="BtnModSave" runat="server" Text="Update" CssClass="btn btn-success" OnClick="UUI" OnClientClick="validate()"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried doing all the actions client-side with JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, that is what I have been trying most recently. I updated the question to show that code as well. Nothing happens on client side when I click BtnModSave

Answer (score 1):

Well, first before doing any web development, you really need to grasp how the page life cycle works. With that knowledge, then everything becomes really simple. Including that of say you clicking a on a regular asp.net button to run some code behind, but also show some kind of "please wait" method.

However, without a grasp of the basic principal of the page life cycle, then all of this will seem like voodoo, and you try endless things that don't work.

So, the FIRST lesson, the FIRST concept you have to grasp is the concept of a post back.

When you click on plain button to run some code behind, then the WHOLE web page is sent up to the server.

The page class is created, loaded, and THEN your code behind runs.

So, say we have this markup:

```
        <asp:Button ID="cmdStart" runat="server" 
            Text="Start the process" CssClass="btn"
            OnClick="cmdStart_Click"
         />

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

So, we will click a button, and start a process with our code behind.

Our code behind is say this:

```
Protected Sub cmdStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)


    TextBox1.Text = "working...."
    ' fake a long process
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000)     ' 5 second delay

End Sub
```

So, will the user see the text box text "become" working... and then a 4 second delay?

Nope! What will occur is the text box in the "DOM" of the page will be changed, then we wait 4 seconds, AND THEN THE WHOLE page makes the trip back down to the browser, is re-loaded, and then we see the changes.

So, the so-called "round trip"?

Code behind can ONLY EVER modify the page WHILE it is up on the server. However, changes made by the server code don't appear client side. (the whole web page is STILL up on the server).

So, you do NOT have this:

[image]

In other words, the web server can ONLY process a post-back page, but from ANY user - not just you!

There is NOT a copy of your page on the server while you are just sitting there looking at the browser.

So, OK, so we click on the button.

We have this:

[image]

So, we click on the button, and the post-back starts.

The web page is now posted to the server.

The server receives that page, loads the page class, creates a instance of the page class (where you code behind exists), and THEN starts to run code behind.

WHILE your code runs, you are changing a copy of the browser on the server. You can change any control - even loop a counter to a control. The end user and their copy of the browser is STILL just sitting on their desktop.

The user can not, will not see changes being made by the code behind.

So, we have this:

[image]

All the end user sees is the browser "spinner" or "wait".

you can load pictures, change text boxes etc. But ALL of that is occurring on the copy of the web page on the server.

At this point, the USER DOES NOT SEE any changes!

Only AFTER 100% of your code is done running, then and ONLY then does a WHOLE NEW FRESH copy of the browser page now makes the trip back down to the client side.

so, now this part of the page "round trip starts".

[image]

The client side browser page THEN loads, renders, starts JavaScript, and THEN the user will now see all the changes your code behind on the server made.

Note that NOW the server will "dispose" and "dump" and "destroy" the code behind and page class. This is why all variables are now out of scope (kind of like calling a sub, when you exit the sub, all values and code in that sub are now gone, out of memory).

the web server is now ready to accept ANY page post back from ANY user - not just you! So NOT EVEN a copy of the code nor web page exists on the server any more!

So, NOW with this new knowledge in mind?

Well, we NOW realize that clicking a button to run some code (server side code behind) means that the end user will NOT see anything change!

So, what this means?

We need to run a bit of code client side FIRST before that post-back button runs!

it turns out that a regular button has provisions for this. So, a simple button click has TWO parts.

A client side event, and a server side event!

So, let's say we want a please wait .... (and say a animated GIF spinner) to display when we click the button.

Well, our button code will this look like this:

```
        <asp:Button ID="cmdStart" runat="server" 
            Text="Start the process" CssClass="btn"
            OnClick="cmdStart_Click"
            OnClientClick="mywaitdialog()"
         />

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>


        <div id="mywaitmsg" style="display:none;width:300px" >
            <h3>Updating data - please wait</h3>
            <div style="text-align: center">
                <img src="../Content/wait2.gif" style="height: 64px; width: 70px" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>

            function mywaitdialog() {
                var mywait = document.getElementById("mywaitmsg")
                mywait.style.display = 'block';
            }

        </script>
```

So, note how the button NOW has two events, and one is the client click.

So, when we click the button, then client side code runs, and SHOWS our hidden div.

Then the above page lifecycle starts.

Note VERY carefully how at the end of the process, we don't have to "hide" the spinner and div message area. (because that page from the server going to come barreling down, and re-load the WHOLE client side page - which of course then hides the div for us!

So, the effect is now this:

[image]

And note our server side button code can be this:

```
    ' fake a long process
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000)     ' 5 second delay
    TextBox1.Text = "done"
```

or, it can be this:

```
    TextBox1.Text = "done"

    ' fake a long process
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000)     ' 5 second delay
```

note the order of where we place the text = "done" does not matter!
(because the page is HELD UP and STAYS on the server until ALL of the code behind is done.

So, as you can see, it really only about 2-3 extra lines of code (client side JavaScript) to display that "wait message".

So, in effect we modify/change/show the wait message client side and THEN let the page life cycle start.

When all is done server side, then a WHOLE NEW copy of the page returns to the client side, and thus no need to even hide the message stuff, since it will revert back to what it was before the button click (the div was hidden with style).

So keep in mind that the code behind NEVER interacts with the user, but ONLY interacts with the copy of the web page that is NOW up on the server. Code behind does not interact with the user, it ONLY can change the page, and only change the page WHILE it is up on the server. So, your code behind in fact does not interact with the user EVER! It only can change the page and controls. the interact ONLY occurs when the WHOLE page makes the trip back down to the client side.

So, while the above to display that wait message was dead simple? It also demonstrates that code behind can't interact with the user. Only code on the page can!

So, a REALLY fantastic next question would be how could I have a progress bar, have 4 or say 8 steps server side, and how would one update the progress bar as we run those 8 steps!

but, for now, for a button to load a gridview, or do whatever that takes a bit of time?

you simple add a client side bit of code to display/show the wait message, and then the server side code can run and go to work. ONLY after all that server side code runs does then the web page up-date. And in our example, we use that fact (the fresh new page) to hide our displayed wait message.

So, with a grasp of the page life cycle, we can leverage the fact that whole new page will arrive sooner or later - and re-load, and re-display the browser.

So, now let's look at your code example:

```
LoadingImg.Visible = True
```

OK, so above changes the visibility of the image - but REMEMBER, this is occurring on the server. The user can't see that change and will ONLY see that change WHEN the whole page travels back to the client side!

Then we have this code:

```
BtnDelete_Click()
BtnSaveSchedule_Click(sender, e, 1)
```

OK, the page is still up on the server side, and you call 2 routines.

(user still has the original copy of their web page on their desktop - they still can't see anything or any changes).

Then this:

```
Call Response.Redirect("~/Schedule.aspx")
```

Hold on! We now are saying to the server do NOT send the current page back to the user, but now we asking the server to jump + load a 100% different page.

So, now the server will nuclear bomb out of existence the current page (that has NOT made the trip back to the end user - so they never see any changes in the browser). The page we were just making changes to now is tossed out into the garbage, and now the we are asking the server to load + start rendering a WHOLE new page. but, the current page NEVER makes the trip back to the client side.

So, we now loading a whole new page. That means ANY changes to the current page we were on can't been seen, and will NEVER be seen by the client side. Specific in this case is this line of code:

```
LoadingImg.Visible = True
```

the user not going to see the above UNLESS we let the whole page travel back to the client side, and finish the round trip!

So, as noted, let's take our example, and change it.

Our code behind is now this:

```
    TextBox1.Text = "done"   ' NEVER will be seen, since next line

    Response.Redirect("MyTestPage2.aspx")
```

So, we change textbox1, but then next line says to jump and render a whole different page.

So, our current page will NEVER travel back to the client. The user NEVER gets to see the text box change to "done", since we NEVER let that page finish the round trip. Since the page NEVER travels back to the client, then they will never see the text box change to "done".
As noted, changes to the browser page by code behind does will NOT be seen when we change the text box, but only AFTER all code is done, and the WHOLE web page then travels back to the client browser. That is when they will see the text box change to "done". Since we then decide to do load a different web page (response redirect), then the user will never see any changes on that current web page - the web page has not traveled back to the client side to display our change to that text box.

So, let's assume that MyTestPage2.aspx has this markup:

```
        <h2>Welcome to test page 2</h2>
```

And let's assume that the page load event of test page 2 is this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)

    End If

End Sub
```

So, what will happen now?

Our button code on the 1st page is still this:

```
        <asp:Button ID="cmdStart" runat="server" 
            Text="Start the process" CssClass="btn"
            OnClick="cmdStart_Click"
            OnClientClick="mywaitdialog()"
         />

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>


        <div id="mywaitmsg" style="display:none;width:300px" >
            <h3>Updating data - please wait</h3>
            <div style="text-align: center">
                <img src="../Content/wait2.gif" style="height: 64px; width: 70px" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>

            function mywaitdialog() {
                var mywait = document.getElementById("mywaitmsg")
                mywait.style.display = 'block';
            }

        </script>
```

so, what will occur is we click on the button.

Our spinner shows, and WHOLE page now is posted to the server.

We do this:

```
Protected Sub cmdStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    TextBox1.Text = "done"

    Response.Redirect("MyTestPage2.aspx")

End Sub
```

We modify text box, but THEN say please load a different page - that is the page that will be sent to the client for our life cycle. We NEVER let the current page go back to the client, did we?

So, our page load event as noted is this in page 2

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)

    End If

End Sub
```

But, the effect again is this:

[image]

So, once again, this all makes sense WHEN you grasp the page lifecycle.

The tell-tale sign that you don't grasp the page life cycle is your line of code behind that tries to set the image visible = true, but THEN you say load (send to client) a 100% different page. So, your visible image setting will never be seen by the client, since we NEVER let the whole page life cycle complete for the first page, but code behind decides to jump to a 100% different page - that is the page the client side browser will receive.

Note that we can put the test sleep delay in the new page load event, or we can put it in the button click code behind. The effect is the same. The client side is STILL waiting for a whole page to return to the client. it don't matter if that is the same current page, or a redirect to a whole new page. The client side will wait and wait until that new page comes down the pipe from the server.

So, if you need a simple "wait", then you simple have to have client side code that runs on that button click. Then the display of that "animated" GIF, or even a simple please wait text will remain in view until such time a whole page is returned from the server. The page returned can be the current page, but with a response redirect, then a different page is returned. but, it still in a sense a page life cycle (in which the client side is waiting for a page to be returned from the server).

So, just keep in mind that code behind "as" it makes changes to the web page are NEVER seen by the user. Any and all changes to that web page are ONLY seen when the WHOLE PAGE on the server makes it's trip back to the client side browser. Then and only then does the browser update. In fact, you can update 1 control, or 20, or set visible of some element. None of these changes will be seen UNTIL THE WHOLE page travels back to the client side.